# Newest tab - sort order is messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, sorting, newest-questions

I watch a number of different tags at the same time using the tag filters and I noticed that today, the sort order of the newest tab seems to have an issue.

Towards the bottom of the first page, I have questions from May 2011 and Dec 2011.  There seems to be questions missing/skipped in the sorted list.

When I check the old questions listed, I can see no recent updates that would have pushed it to the top.  Even so, newest sort order used to be ordered by the question posted date, not active date.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+or+drupal-7+or+ubercart+or+struts2?sort=newest&pagesize=30 for example.

Is this bug?  How can I restore the correct sort order as it was before?

**EDIT**: Just checked again and now it's fixed.  I wonder, what was the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've broadcast a "reload", which has cleared out a lot of buffered / cached data; I don't know why those tags were particularly impacted by stale data - looks like I need to go gremlin hunting... *again*.

Comment: This issue is happening again - noticed as of the time this comment is posted.

Comment: @nmc ok; I think I see the direction my week is heading...

Comment: Bump.  This issue is happening again as of today.  I'm seeing posts listed on my front page from 2011.