# Stale newest question list

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Newest tab - sort order is messed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148976/newest-tab-sort-order-is-messed-up)

The newest questions list for [yii](/questions/tagged/yii) seems to be terribly outdated at the moment, what is wrong?

I read the other questions on caching and such, but this case is extreme. Screenshots:

Chrome:

[image: chrome-screen]

Firefox:

[image: firefox-screen]

Same thing happening with Safari, Opera.

Navigating to the 4th page shows that there were questions asked between Jan 15 and Jan 2:

[image: chrome-4th-page]

Update: Opera:

[image: opera]

Another update Opera:

[image: opera-2]

Comment: What sort are you using? And do it from the first page, not the back 50. Using **Opera** last question was 2 hours ago

Comment: @random sort is newest. And do you mean : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=50` by `do it from the first page, not the back 50`? Last question was 2 hours ago, i'm missing that.

Comment: @random i've added a few more screenshots, please check

Comment: Active, first page, gives this as first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336342/yii-framework-dropdownlist-rules-not-working

Comment: @random it gives me this as first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413013/changing-yii-grid-view-style-from-one-place-in-a-project/14421790#14421790 , it's definitely more recent

Comment: btw, i just modified an answer, so now first, in active page, is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413013/changing-yii-grid-view-style-from-one-place-in-a-project

Comment: just noting here that the active question list seems fine, it's the newest question list that's buggy

Comment: seeing this again today, list is out of order between random refreshing of page, so sometimes it comes in order, but sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be happening [every once in a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148976/197639), list is fixed now.

Comment: seeing this again today, list is out of order between random refreshing of page, so sometimes it comes in order, but sometimes not