# Tag scores have not updated; script did not run

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-score

The tag scores script has not ran at the scheduled time of 03:00 UTC for a number of days.

> **Here are some other reports of this:**
>
> [Is there a problem with tag score calculation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178565/is-there-a-problem-with-tag-score-calculation)
>
> [Tag counts on my profile do not update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178587/tag-counts-on-my-profile-do-not-update)
>
> [When is Top User per Tag Updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178722/when-is-top-user-per-tag-updated)
>
> [Sum of votes on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178777/sum-of-votes-on-tags)

What's going wrong?

---

[My profile tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563422/danny-beckett?tab=tags&sort=name&page=2) states I have a score of 0 across 1 question on [geocoding](/questions/tagged/geocoding):

> [image]

But when I [click the `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1563422%20%5Bgeocoding%5D), it shows that I answered a 2nd question with a score of 2.

> [image]

**Update on 16/05/2013**: The problem relapsed a few days ago and the tag scores are again stale. Can we get this fixed once and for all?

**Update on 14/05/2014**: This has started receiving more upvotes over the last few days. My guess is this has relapsed again.

Comment: Every 6 to 8 weeks (sorry, I had to) :P

Comment: FWIW, the script did get run here on Meta at 03:00... [blahdiblah](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137004/blahdiblah?tab=activity&sort=badges) was awarded the silver discussion badge at 03:00:09 UTC. Looking at other users on SO, it doesn't appear the script ever ran there today.

Comment: Another day has now passed, and the script has still not run.. what's going on?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: It got run today... 03:00 UTC just passed.

Comment: @animuson So it did! Forgot we're in BST now, not GMT.

Comment: another 3am UTC has come and passed with no update to tag totals (about 6h ago, (+- 1h)). :)

Comment: i'm also beginning to see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148976/197639) and [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164329/197639), i.e seeing messed up (out of order) newest question lists in a particular tag, wonder if it is related. between random refreshes of the page i get sometimes a correct order, and sometimes a wrong order.

Comment: Been broken for days for me, hence the bounty

Comment: Been broken for a few days for me too.

Comment: OK, I get it, we're *all* not getting our tag scores updated. Can we stop commenting now? I'm extremely inclined to remove my "informative" answer at this point.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I don't think your answer answers the question. Sure, it tells us when the script is ran, but it doesn't say why it isn't working.

Comment: @mattytommo: Yeah. It was posted at the very minute the script should have run the first time since this question was asked, before any of us could tell that something was wrong. I've removed it now along with all its comments since it's clearly not needed anymore.

Comment: @mattytommo To be fair, the question originally asked *when* the tag scores would be updated. Since I realised it was a bug, I edited it.

Comment: Same problem with my stackoverflow acc.

Comment: Leafless cherry-tree // Tag scores not yet updated // One more day has passed  </fake poetry>

Comment: I am glad, that I am not the only one who is missing the updates (because he is looking at the lists ;-))

Comment: I noticed my tag's score isn't updating from at least 4/5 days.

Comment: I think the badges machine will explode when this problem is fixed and they start delivering badges based on tag score.

Comment: I want my **TAG BADGES!!!!**  Not to be confused with [I want my two dollars](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdF_Vo4B6Ms)!!

Comment: Maybe I have SO MANY pending badges that I broke the batch job? :P

Comment: I think SO staff should say something: there is a bug, some work in progress, the feature was removed, something. You can't stay silent about this for 6 days.

Comment: @dcernahoschi All of the community and developer staff spent the last week in New York. Between meetings and the general disruption to our usual routines, we are a bit behind on meta posts. I'll pass this one along to the dev team.

Comment: Good to see I don't have to submit a new question and this is a known issue. Should be fixed soon now that @Anna is on the case. ;)

Comment: What is happening? No tag total updates for over a week (which is fine, sometimes bad things happen), but no word from *any* SE developers?

Comment: [There we go.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pd5zi.png) Of course, since I don't work for Stack Exchange, I'd do well *not* to post an answer myself.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Ya, without an official dev response, all you can really say is "let's see if it keeps running." I mean, when this was originally posted, it only skipped one day and then ran the next day. Perhaps it just happened not to error out this day and will continue onto another non-running streak tomorrow.

Comment: @animuson: Ah crap I missed that.

Comment: @animuson you were right, it ran yesterday, but not today.

Comment: my tag scores haven't updated yesterday. And wrong (smaller) number of answers is reported for some tags in "tags" tab, too. For some tags, number of posts shown is correct but the total tag rep is off; for others both are off.

Comment: Didn't run for me last night either.

Comment: @AnnaLear, can anyone from SO inside provide an answer tell exactly what happened, is the update script policy changed? I don't care if it is running daily or monthly, most people may satisfied when a clear announcement/explanation is given. Currently the system seems give user a feeling that it is experiencing some unpredictable scenario cause update scripts randomly up and down.

Comment: @Oded can the status-completed tag be removed please for the time being?

Comment: Relevant: [Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226681/223030)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One of our daily scheduled jobs was timing out, causing tag scores to not refresh.

We changed the way we were calling the job that was timing out, so this issue shouldn't recur.

Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: __Issue is back__ I have posted another question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217198/why-tags-stats-are-not-getting-updated-despite-giving-answers

Comment: Looks like it's only getting worse. Maybe make it a weekly process so that at least it's stable and we know when to look forward for it to be updated, like SEDE data?

Comment: FWIW, looks like the issue is back.

Comment: Issue is back, I confirm

Comment: Yes, the issue (or another with the same effect) is recurring.

Comment: I'm not getting impatient but wondering why such a great site can't fix this issue easily. Again, tag score didn't update since last two days :(

Comment: Issue is back - my tagcount have not been updated in three days ...

Comment: @davidkonrad I made a post about this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295680/why-hasnt-the-tag-info-page-updated-within-the-last-few-days?noredirect=1#comment200875_295680 it appears to be working again; I wish they could fix it permanently, however

Comment: It's back.. Or still there.

Comment: Two and half years later, any light in the end of the tunnel? :)

Comment: The issue is still there, haven't seen the update for about a week

Comment: I'm afraid to say it's back..

Comment: Seems it is back. Has not updated for at least 5 days.

Comment: @Cleb Yes mine too. Can we have some feedback about it?

Comment: It seems to be happening again now -- I have some tags that don't seem to show at least a few days of changes.

Answer (score 71):

The tag-score job appears to be running again (yay!), but if it goes down again, or if someone is impatient with the once-a-day updates, I posted [**a page that gets the Tag Scores for a given user**](http://jsbin.com/azeqec/12).

It returns results that are up-to-the-minute (excepting possible caching, by the API, on repeat requests).  The results are fully sortable and searchable.

**Update:**  The page now accepts URL parameters.  EG:
[jsbin.com/azeqec/12?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=1563422](http://jsbin.com/azeqec/12?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=1563422)

Here's what [the page](http://jsbin.com/azeqec/12?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=1563422) looks like for [the OP's current tag scores](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563422/danny-beckett?tab=tags):

<sub>(Click for larger image)</sub>
[image: Sample results]

---

Note that [the API's "top-answer-tags" path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answer-tags-on-users) could not be used, because it appears to be updated by the same daily job at the heart of this question, and it only returns the top 30 results.

Comment: Good one, excellent work! For my id (1983854) I get two different tables. The first one does not order the score properly: I get 97, 9, 9..., 7, 68, 66, 6...

Comment: Interestingly, the first time I loaded the page, it said I had a score of 98 for the HTML tag. Reloading it gave the same as the screenshot. Good job!

Comment: Too bad you missed the +200 bounty by 3 hours... it's a much better answer than Anna's.

Comment: @fedorqui, Fixed the bug whereby tag names that are reserved-words crashed the array sort.  Check out the [new link](http://jsbin.com/azeqec/3).  It should work better for you.

Comment: Great! I cannot +1 again, so here you are a (ferrari) as a modest present for good work :D

Comment: Argh, I'd of gave you the bounty if you'd have replied a little earlier :(

Comment: @mattytommo, no worries.

Comment: This tool deserves hosting that is more permanent than JS Bin.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles: this is great - just one request: can you modify it so the "Answers" link escapes special characters (otherwise, it doesn't work for tags like "c#")

Comment: @RobSiklos, Done.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles: Feature request: I added answer counts too in http://jsbin.com/azeqec/6; this allows you to see if you are eligable for a tag badge or not (100 votes and 20 answers for bronze, 400 votes and 80 answers for silver and 1000 votes and 200 answers for gold).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Okay, added that column to the answer.

Comment: @Awesome: Awesome! :-)

Comment: I went through your code in JS Bin and it's really nice! Great job buddy. Can't upvote you more because I already up-voted you sometime ago. :D God bless your life.