# When is Top User per Tag Updated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow

Is this top user page really updating every day? every week? or every month?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers

I enjoy watching users racing to top every but lately, this page doesn't seem to update.

Comment: I think it's every day at 3:00 UTC..

Comment: @Mysticial so it is a bug? the page was not update since apr 30, 2013. *I guess*

Comment: @SkinnyPipes Yes