# Removed comment activity upon deletion of answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, recent-activity

I wanted to go back to see if any further answers or comments had been posted on a Meta question which I had read through yesterday. I'd forgotten the title of the question and wasn't really sure what to search for as it related to the "Tags" on profiles. I assumed searching for "tags" would return too many results (and I wasn't sure when the question had originally been asked). I had however left a comment on one of the answers, so I figured the way to find the question would be to check my own [activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/211113/james-donnelly?tab=activity&sort=all), only to find that the comment was no longer listed.

In the end I did manage to find the question by searching for "tag": [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run)

It turns out the comment I had left was on an answer which has since been deleted. This has meant that my activity log no longer shows this comment.

Would it not be sensible to keep the activity log but just mention that the content has since been removed? The comment itself doesn't even need to be shown, it could simply be displayed as:

[image: Example]

This way users would be able to get back to questions they'd participated on through their activity log even if the answer had been removed.

Comment: Sensible yes, but I don't think it will be implemented any time soon..