# I've given answers, some of them have been accepted still I do not have any tag score

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

My profile displays I have not participated in any tags, I am not getting why this is happening with me.

Comment: Answers? I only see one answer on your [SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2374721/mr-beans?tab=answers), and it's not accepted (but it earned a bounty, nice!).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run

Comment: This about the 10th question on the topic now...

Comment: Please tell me how does it works, thanks

Comment: @Yannis: Tag scores update problem. My own tag score hasn't got updated for days...

Comment: It is a bug, and it has been reported, fixed, and relapsed again.

Comment: Does anybody has any solution

Comment: @Mr.Beans: Just sit there and wait. Check the link I posted for the temporary solution.

Comment: Caching. Always caching.

Comment: Thanks, to everyone for the help, specially to the one who gave me that link @nhahtdh