# Once again, the per-tag scores have not updated

Tags: bug, tags, tag-score

This has [happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run), but with the [database switch of this weekend](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/66503916324/database-upgrades-complete-nov-9th-2013), the issue might be new once more.

Normally, at around 03:00 AM UTC tag scores and top-30 users lists are updated, but they were not updated today. I use the awesome [jsfiddle-hosted API-based tag table generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179402) to check progress on certain tags, and the numbers for tags I track are clearly stuck.

**Update 2013-11-11**: The tag scores did update this morning, so the glitch appears temporary. I'll monitor this closely and close the report tomorrow if the scores continue to update properly.

**Update 2013-11-12**: Tag scores have updated two days in a row, so the skipped script run from Sunday morning was probably a fluke. Voting to closing this issue.