# Why tags stats are not getting updated after script was supposed to run

Tags: bug, tag-score

I have noticed that for at least a couple of days, the tag stats have not been updating.  It is possible identified in **[Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run)** and marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) has returned.

After spot checking a few of my lower score tags:

- [event](/questions/tagged/event) - I have answered 3 questions, including 1 yesterday, but my tags only show 2 answers.  Additionally, my tag score is shown as 7 but the net total score of my 3 answers is 8.
- [variable](/questions/tagged/variable) -  I have answered 5 questions, including 2 posts 2 days ago, but my tags only show 3 questions.  Additionally, my tag score is shown as 8 but the net total score of my 5 answers is 12.

### This suggests it has been at least 72 hours since the script ran

Comment: @Satpal I've tried to improve your bug report to point out what the issue actually is and hi8ghlighted a couple of tags in your profile that were easy to compute.  If you are not statisfied with the changes, please feel free to roll back, but i think this explains the problem a little better for the dev team.

Comment: @Spatal should be clear from the comments in the original question/answer that we know that this has been going on longer than one day. Rather that duplicating the bug report, upvote, add a comment or suggest an edit on the original question/answer.

Comment: @m0sa Should we remove the "status completed" tag from the original question then? It hasn't been running for the last three days.

Comment: [That](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run) was another occasion, which got fixed.

Comment: @m0sa So if that was an occasion that got fixed, while this one is in the process of being fixed, shouldn't it be reopened until the problem is fixed? Closing an active issue as a duplicate of a resolved issue is incorrect.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the issue linked to in the duplicate notice is not resolved yet, no status-* tag, we're working on it. and it's the same issue as reported here, just witnessed by another user

Comment: My tags score is the same for more than 4 days already... http://stackoverflow.com/users/114029/leniel-macaferi?tab=tags