# Again problems with tags not refreshing

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page

It seems, that the problem happens not the first time ([Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run))

Just now the state of uml tag on my profile is about 7 days old.

A year ago it was told: "We changed the way we were calling the job that was timing out, so this issue shouldn't recur. " - I am afraid, something broke the process again.

And the problem exists for about a month already: look at the comment below the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180679/176427).