# Are the answers & votes counts for tags currently broken?

Tags: support, bug, tags, badges

I noticed that I seem to have been stalled on at least one of my tag counts for quite a while now. I have just tested by noting my counts for a given tag then posting an answer in that tag - sure enough the count next to that tag on my profile page has not changed, (yes I have refreshed & closed re-opened, etc).

This is frustrating as I have been ten away from a silver for one tag for some time now and have had several up-votes in the intervening time.

Comment: The script times out intermittently.

Comment: I use [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179402) to track progress for tag upvotes.

Comment: I guess that it has again!  Love the link @MartijnPieters.