# When will tags be updated?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-score

On my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758701/refdev?tab=profile) top tag scores seem to be in an old state. Or how does it work? Are these scores received reputations? What are scores there? And the votes? Questions and answers count equal?

The whole top tag section is not being updated. There is a similar [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run), but this one is about the new profile main page, where the "scores" term appears. For me its meaning is unclear.

Comment: Caching, perhaps?

Comment: There run several script to update and award badges, tags etc. Some run on an hourly basis, some run on a daily basis. If this issue still seems to be the case in 24 hours there might be an issue.

Comment: @rene, this is the correct answer, after a day it updated! But still, what are scores?

Comment: @refdev the score is the number of question you asked/answered (the x 10 behind a tag) and the reputation you gained with those posts. (the number in front of the tag)

Comment: On the linked screen, there aren't any numbers in front of the tag. (I linked the top tags from the new profile.) You are probably talking about the screen that appears by pressing the view all tags below this top tag section.