# How low is low, really? (aka What triggers the "Keeping a low profile"?)

Tags: support, profile-page

Please take a look on [this profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147223/satamusic?tab=profile):

> [image]

Now [other profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/310190/jee-gog?tab=profile), on same site:

> [image]

Both have no posts. Why one showing the "Keeping a low profile" message, while the other is not?

My first impression was that maybe having no posts and no badges trigger the low profile message, however [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147452/user147452?tab=profile) disproves that theory - got a badge, yet the low profile message is there.

Comment: The one who "has not asked or answered any questions" has a few top tags with 1 post and -3 score. So he/she has a deleted post.

Comment: @ff524 thanks, however I'm 100% sure [this user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/309967/f470071?tab=profile) also has at least one deleted post, yet it's showing the "low profile" message. So this might be caching issue, as always.

Answer (score 3):

Led by [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270019/how-low-is-low-really-aka-what-triggers-the-keeping-a-low-profile#comment874879_270019), I think I solved the mystery. The "Keeping a low profile" appears when the user has no posts, and **did not participate in any tags.**

For example, that second user used in my example [has "participated" in tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/310190/jee-gog?tab=tags):

> [image]

All of these for a single answer, which was deleted two hours ago:

> [image]

When the tag score calculation will run, those tags will be nuked from the user's profile and "Keeping a low profile" will appear. However, this might take days, even weeks on sites like Stack Overflow as reported two and half years ago, and not yet fixed: [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run)