# Some tag counters are not increasing

Tags: support, bug, tags, tag-score

It's been a few days since some of my tag counters are not increasing. Typically, I can see the [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) counter increasing when I get upvotes, but my other tags (such as [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), [php](/questions/tagged/php)) are not having their counters increased.

Here is a snapshot of my activity dashboard taken today at 1:46 UTC:

- [sql](/questions/tagged/sql): 715
- [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql): 396
- [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server): 98
- [php](/questions/tagged/php): 93

[image]

Times goes by and I get a few upvotes:

[image]

The [first two upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975725/generate-query-using-5-tables/54975835#54975835) relate to a question tagged [sql](/questions/tagged/sql)/[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), and the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972982/how-to-inner-join-the-correct-value-from-2-values-in-the-table-where-1-is-correc/54974625#54974625) to [sql](/questions/tagged/sql)/[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)/[php](/questions/tagged/php).

More than 30 minutes later, now 3h30 UTC, looking at my dashboard, only [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) had its counter increased, not the others:

[image]

My [tag tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb?tab=tags) is showing the same information.

How come? I believe this has been happening for several days now.

---

I understand that there are various questions around about this type of issue, specifically [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run). But it was supposedly solved 5 years ago. So what is to say? Should we just wait for issue to disappear? Is there anywhere we can find information about when problem occurs, how they impact users, and when they get solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run) (I don't know why that question has [tag:status-completed], as it keeps recurring over and over again.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I read this post, but this bug was supposedly solved in 2013...

Comment: "Supposedly" is the keyword. There are a dozen or more later dupes documenting recurrences, so AFAICT it was just a quick hack to clear things up for a month or two.

Comment: So what is to say? Should we just wait for issue to disappear? Is there anywhere we can find information about when problem occurs, how they impact users, and when they get solved?

Comment: No, we should *not* just wait for this issue to disappear. This is a useful bug report; hopefully it will be fixed for real this time.

Comment: Thanks @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle... Unsure that this question should be closed as a duplicate, since it relates to an on-going issue, as opposite to the other one.

Comment: No, I don't think it should. The other bug report was, as you said, supposedly fixed, but it actually wasn't. That's enough to qualify for a separate bug report.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle : Well... It should not but it was...

Comment: I see 719 (+4) for sql, 403 (+7) for mysql, 100 (+2) for sql-server, and 94 (+1) for php now.

Comment: @Bookends: thanks, yes I saw counters moved up a little... I highly doubt, however, that all missing points were recovered (issue has been on-going for a few days and I gained more points during that period). Do you have any information about a known on-going problem on SO, or is it specific to my account?

Comment: @Bookends : go two upvotes since this morning : one for [tag:mysql] (and other tags), the other for [tag:sql-server] (and others)... and  my counters for these tags did not increase : figures are the same as when you posted your message, ie [tag:mysql]=403, [tag:sql-server]=100. Looks like the issue somehow persists!