# Sort order of "newest" tagged questions broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

The sort order of "newest" tagged questions seems to be currently broken on SO.

Maybe it's the same (or a similiar) issue [as we already had in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148976/160003)?

Or is it just me?

**Update**:

Now (about 1.5 hours later) the issue is gone for me.

I don't know what fixed the issue, but since I haven't changed anything in my SE accounts or browser, I guess it was some stale cache or whatever.

---

Example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*http*?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=30
```

[image: Sort order newest on *http*]

Another example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*magento*?sort=newest&pagesize=30
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It' not a bug, the newest tagged questions page looks fine.

You are using `*http*` in the first url and [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) tag in the second url that's why it is showing a vast time difference between the questions.

Comment: These URLs are produced by the system. They're not handmade. And there are definitely dozens of new questions per day in the magento tag. So you're saying they're not shown by intention?

Comment: @JürgenThelen, in the magento tagged questions page, there is no questions seemed to be hidden, it looks good.

Comment: @JürgenThelen Unable to reproduce the star in the url.

Comment: @Daedalus: Using "Favorite Tags -> Add" allows this. My favorites are some years old, but just tested it to be sure. It still works.

Comment: @JürgenThelen Still unable to reproduce.

Comment: @Daedalus: Hm, cleared my browsers caches, forced page reloads, no proxy in between. Still the same issue. Using FF 22.0.

Comment: @JürgenThelen Just tested on FF 22.0; norepo.

Comment: @Daedalus: then it seems that it's just me, I guess. Thanks for your kind help trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JürgenThelen I would check firefox for any weird extensions, it could be the cause if something slipped through the cracks of your security.

Comment: @Daedalus: cross-tested with IE 10. I see the same issue there. Now I'm almost sure it must be something specific with my SO account.