# Sorting questions by date doesn't seem to be working properly for less popular tags

Tags: bug, questions, sorting

I have 3 tags that I actively follow:  [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass), and [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox).  Questions seem to sort correctly under the CSS tag just fine, but it is an extremely active tag.  The other tags aren't that active and frequently display questions out of order.  Looking at the Sass tag first page, here's the dates:

- asked 11 hours ago
- asked 17 hours ago
- asked 18 hours ago
- asked 22 hours ago
- asked 23 hours ago
- asked yesterday
- asked 2 days ago
- asked Jul 12 at 23:19 (note that this was over a month ago)
- asked May 13 at 6:47
- asked Apr 17 at 14:24
- asked Apr 15 at 0:08
- asked Mar 14 at 23:28

Page 2 shows questions as old as 2011, and page 3 returns to questions from August. I've double checked my tabs to make sure I am looking at "newest" instead of "featured" or any of the other options, and they definitely are "newest".

Comment: Happens only in the "newest"  view, "active" view appears to be fine. It's all cached, and it's pretty frequent the cache order is messed up, always to be sorted by itself within couple of hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newest tab - sort order is messed up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148976/newest-tab-sort-order-is-messed-up)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks, I did a search but all the results that came back were regarding answers.