# Why did this question suddenly appear as the second newest unanswered rspec question even though it's one year old?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface

The question is [rspec factory girl associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922256/rspec-factory-girl-associations) and it shows up as follows when I use [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/rspec%20or%20rspec2)

> [image]

- Note there is a question that looks similar but is essentially different, as it's a 1 year old, status-completed bug report: [Newest tab - sort order is messed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148976/newest-tab-sort-order-is-messed-up)

Comment: What steps did you take, as to replicate the problem?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Looks like unanswered > newest to me.

Comment: Yeah, but according to user preferences, results get skewered and filtered.

Comment: I added the URL I used

Comment: I can replicate. The weird thing is if I used the tags separately, I don't get that post. I'm checking the timestamps and they aren't quite well ordered, some seem like they were made yesterday and the next follows in 8 hours... From what I'm seeing, it looks like a bug in the sorting algorithm (or perhaps a caching issue) that has some trouble differentiating days.

Comment: Is this really a dupe of a 1 year old, status-completed bug report?

Comment: @Matt Sorry, my bad. I do remember seeing this recently though — the “newest” subtab under “Unanswered” going by ”modified“ date — but I can't find it now. It may have been on a child meta.

Comment: @Matt I read some more posts linked to those I pointed in the duplicate, and it seemed as this was a "slightly" recurring problem, as to one poster having said something in the likes of "hunting gremlins".